# What is the best way to open a file for editing from a web page

Tags: network-shares, intranet

I'm looking for a way to create an index of files on a web page hosted on out intranet.

The files are located on various network shares, eg \nas\documents\tender.doc

When a user clicks on the file I want the file to be opened on there PC with whatever program they have associated with it. eg *.txt open with notepad++, *.doc with word etc

The user needs to be able to edit the file and then save it in its original location.

I don't want the user to have to download the file, edit it and then upload it.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't think the given command runs as SYSTEM. Why do you need to run something "as SYSTEM" but with alternate credentials anyway?

Comment: And how do you plan on capturing the user's password, and storing it encrypted until the program needs it? (Neither of which you should be doing. Passwords should be hashed - and then some - not encrypted. But you'd need to use encryption if you were planning to re-use the plaintext as a command argument in the first place. And nothing should be capturing the user's password to begin with except the system/application for which it was designed to be used.)

Comment: If you're actually writing a program, there's probably a dozen better ways to do this with API calls or somesuch. Unfortunately, that's out-of-scope here. Try [so].

Comment: Also, why do you feel the need to run your program as a service, as SYSTEM? Plenty of background processes run as the current user. And if you'll need to prompt the user for credentials otherwise anyway, you may as well just run it with the user's token to begin with and just minimize to tray until needed afterward.

Comment: I suggest instead looking through [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474702/), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465010/), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/) - then, if you're still stuck, [here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=link+to+file+share+html&oq=link+to+file+share+html) - for solutions that *don't* involve running additional software on end-users' computers, or capturing their passwords, first.

Comment: I had tried [locallink for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida) but it just saves a copy.
[locallink for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/locallink/) works perfectly. 
shame there isn't a solution for chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `psexec` command, but without `-p SomePassword`. You should be prompted to enter the password, and your input will not be displayed on-screen.

If this is part of a batch script, put the following at the start of the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
```

That will disable command echoing to the terminal, so the commands in the script will not be displayed as they run. Command output will still be displayed.

If you want to leave command echoing on, but just hide this one, precede it with an `@` sign. Example:

```
@ PSExec.exe -accepteula -h -d -u someUser -p somePassword -i 1 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE /c start "" "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CALC.EXE
```

Do bear in mind that the password will still be available as plaintext in the script file. In general, that's a bad idea.

Comment: @JamesG See my update, and comment to your question.

Comment: @JamesG And we're back to why putting passwords into scripts is a bad idea. Again, why are you doing this to begin with? I'm still having a hard time thinking of a use case for "run as SYSTEM, then let system run as a different user".

Comment: @JamesG In the script or in memory, the point is it's being stored in a place and manner which is not secure. If you're worried about an attacker dedicated enough to know and bother to check the parameters in Task Manager, you should be just as worried (if not more so) about the one who's going to be scraping the system's RAM.

Comment: @JamesG I'm confused. I inferred from your earlier comment, "I should have added it is for an automated task", that entering the password interactively is not an option. If it is, what's the problem with using **runas**?

Comment: @AdiInbar I think the intent is to avoid entering it every time he wants to use the script. i.e.: The program launches, the user enters their password once, and then the script can be run as many times as needed afterward (until logoff/shutdown) without prompting for another user input. Regardless, it all reeks of bad security practice.

Comment: @JamesG Dare I ask: Why aren't you just using file shares?

Comment: Is there a problem with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474702/link-to-a-file-share-through-an-anchor-tag)? e.g.: `<A HREF="file://///nas/folder/file.txt">Here's a link to File.txt in Folder on NAS.</A>`

Comment: Most browsers these days are intelligent enough to seek out or prompt the user for an external application (with many built-in as defaults upon install) when the browser itself cannot open a certain file. Also, be aware that linking to file shares may not work on pages served over plain HTTP due to default browser restrictions. (Though testing of pages stored in the local file system worked fine for me.) This is for very good security reasons that should not be tampered with.

Comment: I suggest Googling for "link to file share html" to find more information/workarounds. Interestingly enough, the top four non-advertisement results are from [so].

Comment: @Iszi The method in my answer can be used to enter the password interactively as well. The clarification I was seeking from the OP was whether that's what he really wants to do. If so, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AdiInbar I think that point is really moot right now. This is obviously an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @JamesG So, here's the question we haven't asked yet... why are you trying to link to files on a share? Why not just post the files on the site?

Comment: @Iszi - Because the users want to edit the files. If I put them on the site then they would have to download them, edit them and then upload them again. Furthermore, by opening them on the file share it puts a write-lock on the file so only one user can edit it at a time. Don't get me wrong its not the ideal solution - when I started here we had spreadsheets acting as indexes to other SS, I'm trying to make the Intranet the index and slowly migrate the SS to DBs with forms. This is only a transitional step.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is SharePoint, or a comparable solution.

Comment: If you change your answer to SharePoint I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell, you can store the username and encrypted password in a text file. The automated task can read the credentials credentials from the text file and create a PSCredential object, the use **Start-Process** to launch the executable using those credentials.

1. Store the credentials:

   ```powershell
   $path = <path_to_text_file>
   Read-Host "Username" | Out-File $path
   Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -Append $path
   ```

   Note that **ConvertFrom-SecureString** does *not* decrypt the secure string into plain text; it converts it to cryptotext that can be stored in a file. After running this, you'll have a file with two lines. Line 1 contains the username, and line 2 contains the encrypted password.
2. In the automated task, read the credentials and use them to launch the executable in that accounts context:

   ```powershell
   $stored_creds = Get-Content <path_to_text_file>
   $username = $stored_creds[0]
   $password = $stored_creds[1] | ConvertTo-SecureString
   $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $password
   Start-Process <path_to_executable> -Credential $credential
   ```

   Note that `<path_to_executable>` is just that: the path to the executable, not the full command line (`'C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe'` in your example). If you have any arguments, tack on `-ArgumentList <the_rest_of_the_command_line>`.

Comment: "Decrypt", "Hash"... I do not think these words mean what you think they mean. "Hashes" cannot be "decrypted". Regardless, this doesn't address the issue the OP mentioned of being able to see the parameters used for PSExec in the end. (Neither does mine, at this point, but I'm leaving it up for the comment thread at the moment.)

Comment: The term "hash" means several different things. One of the common meanings is the cryptotext produced by a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). And yes, this absolutely addresses the issue. At no point is the password exposed. It does get stored in plain text in RAM while the script is running, but if you're concerned about the possibility of the RAM location being paged out and captured from the pagefile, you can skip the variable assignment and replace `$Password` on the second line with the expression assigned to it on the first line.

Comment: 1. You should read your own wiki links. The very first sentence says, effectively, that hashes cannot be decrypted - they are one-way functions. 2. This *still* does *not* address the issue. Any time you run `PSExec` (doesn't matter how you do it) the parameters passed to it must be converted to clear plaintext (otherwise they'll be unusable by `PSExec`) and then those parameters will be available by viewing `PSExec.exe` in Task Manager and choosing to show the "Command Line" column.

Comment: The password, being one of those parameters, will then be plainly available to anyone with Administrator access (or access as the user who ran `PSExec`) as long as `PSExec` is still running - which is for as long as the process `PSExec` spawned is running. It doesn't require any specialized programming or exploits at all.

Comment: @Iszi Okay, I see what you mean, you're right on both counts, I just hadn't thought it through carefully. The output of **ConvertFrom-SecureString** can't be a hash if it's reversible. And the password can be seen in Process Monitor if it's supplied as a command line argument to **psexec** by *any* means. In that case...I'm still not sure what the problem is with using **runas** or just using **psexec** without the **Password** argument and being prompted. But in any case, **Start-Process** is always an option...

Comment: The problem is he doesn't want to prompt the user for input every time his script needs to be run. Besides that, as I stated earlier, this whole thread is just a classic XY Problem. He's asking "How can I run a program as SYSTEM, and then make that program open a file as another user." when he *should* be asking "How can I put a link to a file that's on a network share, on a webpage?". And I've got an odd feeling that even *that* isn't the bottom of this rabbit hole, but I'm fine with leaving it there.

Comment: Setting aside the XY issue and looking at the question as asked, in that case it's not clear to me where the password is supposed to come from. There are only two ways I can think of: read it from a file, or prompt the user. He needs to clarify in which way he expects the credentials to be supplied.

Comment: The commands are being output from a program, so either I need to pass the password as an argument or I could make the user enter the password once as part of the setup procedure. I looked into using runas and start-process, but neither of them work if your logged in as system.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference what account you're logged in as, since you're supplying the credentials to those commands. The question is from where the script is supposed to obtain those credentails. If you want to make the user enter the credentials once as part of the setup procedure, then storing the encrypted password in a text file and reading it back as I suggested in my answer is exactly what you want. The only problem is exposing it through **psexec**, so you should use **Start-Process** instead. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Is shouldn't make a difference but it does, I think you'll find you get an access denied error if you SYSTEM tries to use Start-Process to  launch as another user. I would suggest opening a command prompt as system "psexec -sid cmd" and then try running your powershell in there. [Post on the issue](http://superuser.com/questions/550170/problems-with-runas-and-system-account)

Comment: Works perfectly as a standard user, but as SYSTEM I get the following error: "Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied."

Comment: The latest revision of this answer is much better than the one that used `PSEXEC`. However, the password can still be converted back to plaintext by the same mechanism as was used in the previous revision. This does raise the level of difficulty from "Joe Power User" to "Joe PowerUser who really knows his PowerShell", but you should remain aware that the protection offered here can still be bypassed by any user who can read the file in which you've stored the encrypted password.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? Particularly, have you tested running the script with an account other than the one that was used to store the password? I got a "Key not valid for use in specified state." error. I think there's more work needed to make this function - particularly creation of a shareable key to be used by the script. (Correction to earlier note: Password's not readable by just any user, with the given script as-is. However, for the script to be made usable, it probably be.)